# SSRS Parameter Date Expression

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I am looking for a default Date Parameter Expression which i would like to SSRS Start Date Time field to a specific date i.e 25/01/2017 07:00:00:000
I currently have an expression which will only give me a date
=DateValue("January 25,2017")

Could someone help please?

Comment: Don't worry guys, i manage to include this on SQl itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
=Format(Parameters!yourParameter.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```